# Connecting to a Server with Laptops

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-access, connection, laptop

We have a small office with 7 staff that work in it. We have recently got hold of a server in the bid to keep office work separate to private work. What is the best way for the laptops to connect to the server in a remote desktop kind of way? I know remote desktop only allows 2 connections at a time and we would need all 7 connected at a time. Is this even possible?
the server is running windows server 2008 R2

the server is a dell poweredge 1850 with 8 GB RAM DDR2 400Mhz in at the moment, there are two 3.6GHz Intel Xeon CPU (800Mhz) - 64-Bit - Hyper-Threaded

Comment: I think you'll need to have a look at the Terminal Services server role...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to purchase some Remote Desktop Services (aka Terminal Services) CALS, and then setup Terminal Services / Gateway.

Here is a guide on what you need to do : http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/configuring-windows-server-2008-terminal-services-gateway-part1.html

Comment: Can I not get RDS CALS to allow more users to connect? or does this still leave it at 2?

Comment: You need the CALS to legally do it. Terminal services will allow you to have as many users connect as your server will support (resource-wise)

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @Robin Gill you will require Remote desktop Services.  You will need the CALS and the setup and also pay close attention to total RAM as each session uses RAM. Processor Cores will also be needed so that each session is not very slow.  Basically, you need a good server.  Definition of Good needs to be determined based on what users are doing and how many at same time.

Note that application licenses will likley be needed as well.

Careful planning should give you the  results you require.

If you can give more deatil on the server hardware and what apps users will run, a better answer can be given.

Please add info around the apps used by the users so the server hardware can be better evaluated.  If each user is assigned 1GB of RAM, you can see how performance could be poor.

Comment: the server is a dell poweredge 1850 with 8 GB RAM DDR2 400Mhz in at the moment, there are two 3.6GHz Intel Xeon CPU (800Mhz) - 64-Bit - Hyper-Threaded if this is any help?

Comment: No, since we don't know the application's i/o load. And if it will work properly with multi-users on the server.

Comment: You need to audit your licensing requirements for the server access/CALS, and your office software. Just because you bought a license of some sort doesn't mean the company allows you to use it like this on a terminal...

Comment: @ Bart Silverstrim points out critical issues around licenses.  Pay close attention.